# when I import my module to npm in my another project I have error ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I have a module npm and it is using the ES6 syntax, when I using the `npm i myModuleName` I have an error with syntax import and export.

My code

```
'use strict';

import merge from 'ngraph.merge'
import createGraph from 'ngraph.graph'
import fetch from './lib/loader'

module.exports = async function convertPrecompute(graph, layout, settings){

    settings = merge(settings,{
        positionsPos: 'data/positions.bin',
        linksPos: 'data/links.bin',
        labelsPos: 'data/labels.json',
    });

    await Promise.all([
        fetch(settings.positionsPos, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(toInt32Array),
        fetch(settings.linksPos, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(toInt32Array),
        fetch(settings.labelsPos).then(toJson)
      ]).then(loadLayout);

    function loadLayout(data){
        let positions = data[0];
        let links = data[1];
        let labels = data[2];

        graph = initGraphFromLinksAndLabels(links, labels);

        labels.forEach(function (label, index) {
            var nodeCount = index * 3;
            var x = positions[nodeCount + 0];
            var y = positions[nodeCount + 1];
            var z = positions[nodeCount + 2];

            layout.setNodePosition(label, x, y, z);
        });
    }

    function initGraphFromLinksAndLabels(links, labels) {
        let srcIndex;

        let g = createGraph({ uniqueLinkId: false });
        labels.forEach(label => g.addNode(label));
        links.forEach(processLink);

        return g;

        function processLink(link) {
          if (link < 0) {
            srcIndex = -link - 1;
          } else {
            var toNode = link - 1;
            var fromId = labels[srcIndex];
            var toId = labels[toNode];
            graph.addLink(fromId, toId);
          }
        }
      }
}

function toInt32Array(oReq) {
    return new Int32Array(oReq.response);
}

function toJson(oReq) {
    return JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);
  }
```

I'm using this submodules in another project with Browserify and yeoman with [this configuration](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify.md)

when running the app with the `gulp serve` I'm getting this error

```
/home/vincenzo/GitLab/spycblock-ngraph/node_modules/ngraph.fromprecompute/index.js:12
import merge from 'ngraph.merge'
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

if I change the code in the my submodule with ES5 it work, an example of my submodule with ES5

```
'use strict';

let merge = require('ngraph.merge');
let createGraph = require('ngraph.graph')
let fetch = require('./lib/loader')

//Startup https://dev.to/therealdanvega/creating-your-first-npm-package-2ehf
module.exports = async function convertPrecompute(graph, layout, settings){

    settings = merge(settings,{
        positionsPos: 'data/positions.bin',
        linksPos: 'data/links.bin',
        labelsPos: 'data/labels.json',
    });

    await Promise.all([
        fetch(settings.positionsPos, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(toInt32Array),
        fetch(settings.linksPos, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(toInt32Array),
        fetch(settings.labelsPos).then(toJson)
      ]).then(loadLayout);

    function loadLayout(data){
        let positions = data[0];
        let links = data[1];
        let labels = data[2];

        graph = initGraphFromLinksAndLabels(links, labels);

        labels.forEach(function (label, index) {
            var nodeCount = index * 3;
            var x = positions[nodeCount + 0];
            var y = positions[nodeCount + 1];
            var z = positions[nodeCount + 2];

            layout.setNodePosition(label, x, y, z);
        });
    }

    function initGraphFromLinksAndLabels(links, labels) {
        let srcIndex;

        let g = createGraph({ uniqueLinkId: false });
        labels.forEach(label => g.addNode(label));
        links.forEach(processLink);

        return g;

        function processLink(link) {
          if (link < 0) {
            srcIndex = -link - 1;
          } else {
            var toNode = link - 1;
            var fromId = labels[srcIndex];
            var toId = labels[toNode];
            graph.addLink(fromId, toId);
          }
        }
      }
}

function toInt32Array(oReq) {
    return new Int32Array(oReq.response);
}

function toJson(oReq) {
    return JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);
  }
```

Comment: Just a side note: In an ESM module, you don't need `'use strict';` at the top. ESM modules are always strict. (Sorry I don't know how to fix the actual problem. :-) )

Comment: thanks for this fix